# how do I add JRE to Spring Tool Suite

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I've just installed JDK 16 on MacOS:

```
java version "16.0.1" 2021-04-20
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 16.0.1+9-24)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 16.0.1+9-24, mixed mode, sharing)
```

$echo $JAVA_HOME

```
/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home
```

So now how do I define new JRE in STS in Installed JREs window?
Which folder do I pick up?

[image]

Comment: Just add `/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home` (or the folder of the JRE/JDK you want to use) in the JRE home? However, I strongly recommend using a JDK rather than just a JRE.

Comment: when I try to /Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home it in JRE home: field it says "The home directory does not exits"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

windows->preferences->installed JRE -
JRE Home :go to sts installed folder c:\...\sts-4.10.0.RELEASE\plugins\org.eclipse.justj.openjdk.hotspot.jre.full.win32.x86_64_15.0.2.v20210201-0955\jre.
**[image: strong text]**

Comment: Note that tge OP uses MacOS so the `c:` is not accurate.